# I am trying to run Docker, but it is showing me an error

Tags: docker

I am trying to install datahub on my machine. After I run the command

```
datahub docker quickstart
```

I am getting this

```
✔ Container datahub-elasticsearch-1        Created                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 ✔ Container datahub-zookeeper-1            Created                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 ✔ Container datahub-elasticsearch-setup-1  Created                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 ✔ Container datahub-broker-1               Created                                                                                                                                                   0.0s 
 ⠹ Container datahub-mysql-1                Starting                                                                                                                                                  0.2s 
Error response from daemon: network 0784b1276e5d504d55af002e0f5bbc3b3c267e864f3fc15b870e771c7343e18a not found
```

How to make the Docker run so that I can work on the datahub?

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Based on [the docs](https://datahubproject.io/docs/quickstart/), it may be worth trying `datahub docker nuke` and then running the `quickstart` command again.